# Show Keyboard to enter text in text filed on tableview cell click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I need to display the keyboard to enter text into a textfield. But I need the keyboard to appear when I simply click anywhere on the tableview cell. Currently you have to click the textfield in the cell for the keyboard to appear. In the tableview cell I have a Label (which does not have to be edited by the user) and the textfield for the user to enter a value. I would appreciate any assistance. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You can handle this in the `didSelectRowAt` delegate method of `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! YourCell
    cell.yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I am new to this.. It looks like I have to cast to "YourCell" does this mean I have to make a 'custom' tableViewCell, note I am using Static tableViews. What is the best way to do this?